# Typescript object extends the Array<BoxModel> can not call the inside methods anymore

Tags: arrays, typescript, ionic2, extends

After upgrading to Ionic3 which is using the newest Typescript version (2.2.1) I am facing the big issue. I have one normal Typescript class BoxList which extends the Array. So it is normal array with some additional custom methods that I use. I have a method called "allHit" which loops through the array and returns the boolean value. The thing is, that in Ionic2 everything was working fine, but after the upgrade, I can not call the `this.boxList.allHit` method anymore because it throws me an exception:

> -> main.js:1 ERROR TypeError: this.boxList.allHit is not a function(…)

Code:

```
import {BoxModel} from "./BoxModel";
export class BoxList extends Array<BoxModel> {

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    public allHit(boxTarget: BoxModel) : boolean {
        return this.findIndex(box => box.doesMatch(boxTarget) && !box.isHit) === -1;
    }

    public findUntouchedBox() : BoxModel {
        return this.find(box => !box.isHit);
    }
}
```

And the call of the allHit method from other object:

```
public allBoxesAreHit() : boolean {
    return this.boxList.allHit(this.targetBox);
}
```

Does someone have a clue what is going on here? Thanks!

Comment: can you add the function to your question?

Comment: Hey! I added the whole class.

Comment: can you add the function call as well pls?

Comment: Thanks. Also added the function call. Do you know what is wrong here?

Comment: check my answer.. its a typescript change..ionic 2 was using 2.0.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Typescript 2.1 [breaking changes](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes#extending-built-ins-like-error-array-and-map-may-no-longer-work):

> As part of substituting the value of this with the value returned by a super(...) call, subclassing Error, Array, and others may no longer work as expected. This is due to the fact that constructor functions for Error, Array, and the like use ECMAScript 6's new.target to adjust the prototype chain; however, there is no way to ensure a value for new.target when invoking a constructor in ECMAScript 5.

Try their recommendation and set:

```
constructor() { 
   super(); 
  Object.setPrototypeOf(this, BoxList.prototype); 
}
```

in the constructor.

Comment: Wow that actually works! My constructor looks like this now:
    constructor() {
        super();
        Object.setPrototypeOf(this, BoxList.prototype);
    }

Comment: Typescript has changed a lot from 2.0.9 to 2.2.1.. its quite a jump.. you should go through the rest of it